# How to stop meta-rpm transaction if a precondition fails?

Tags: yum, rpm

I currently have a meta-package rpm which contains a list of dependencies on other rpm packages.

I want to stop the update/install transaction of the meta-package (and all subsequent packages) if the pre-install script fails (i.e. when returning a value other than 0).

I tried this by putting the test condition in the meta-package pre-install script, seems reasonable, but here's what happened:

```
# yum update my-package
```

1. meta-package checks which dependent packages will have to be updated/installed
2. runs the meta-package pre-install script and fails (in this case)
3. continues the update procedure and updates subsequent packages (!)

Thus, I end up in a situation where:

- the meta-package version is not updated
- all dependent packages *might* be updated to a more recent version

This can clearly cause some severe issues if the meta-package contains data required for the other packages.

Is there any way to stop the full transaction if the pre-install condition fails?

*Note*: I've tried also the update procedure with the rpm command, did not work either.